# LibreELEC PVR not functioning

Tags: pi-zero, kodi

I am new to RPi and LibreELEC, and want to get working live TV and recording. I bought myself an Xbox One TV tuner which I have heard is compatible with Raspberry Pi. So I boot up my Pi, go onto TV and download an add-on for PVR. When I try and go back onto the TV section, it says "PVR manager is starting up: 0%" and it stays like that for hours, not making progress. I have tried Tvheadend, ,MythTV DVBlink and VDR, and none of them work. The aerial cable I am using definitely works because I use it for my TV. BTW, I've got a Pi zero with the tuner attached to the USB hub, if that info helps. Anyone got ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: can you ssh into the pi? makes troubleshooting 10x easier in my opinion. Also, in my opinion, pi zero is underpowered to do plain ol' kodi, let alone adding a tv tuner to it - again, that's just an opinion, so dont' read too much into it :p